# NgSwitch loses async data on switch?

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I've run into a little snafu right now. I am displaying posts in a user's profile based on a *ngSwitch:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="iconsMediaSegment">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'grid'">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async" col-4 class="col-image">
          <img [src]='post.image'>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>

  <div *ngSwitchCase="'list'">
    <page-feed-item class="post-list" *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async"  [feed]="post" ></page-feed-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now this works perfectly when it is by itself, and I can switch between the two segments without any issues. But I also want to keep a counter of the async'd data in an earlier part of the view like so:

```
  <ion-col>
    <p>Posts</p>
    <span *ngIf="posts$">{{ (posts$ | async)?.length }}</span>
  </ion-col>
```

Now, when the page first loads, the first segment (grid) has the post images, the `{{ (posts$ | async)?.length }}`  has the number of posts, we're in a perfect world. But the issue arises when I try to switch to the other segment (list), the posts disappear completely from both the grid segment and the list segment.

Now I know that a simple fix to this is to just add a new observable that is an exact replica of posts$, but just call it something like postsCount$, and async that length instead, but I am trying to understand why the original method doesn't work, and what else I could do to fix it, without the redundant code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might work for your case:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="posts$ | async as posts">

  <ion-col>
    <p>Posts</p>
    <span>{{ posts.length }}</span>
  </ion-col>

  <div [ngSwitch]="iconsMediaSegment">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'grid'">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col *ngFor="let post of posts" col-4 class="col-image">
            <img [src]='post.image'>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'list'">
      <page-feed-item class="post-list" *ngFor="let post of posts"  [feed]="post" ></page-feed-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Note that unlike your version this one doesn't make a new request every time you switch between views.

You can test it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykenpw
Open the network tab and notice only one request, then implement it your way and watch a request being sent every time you toggle view.

Comment: That works flawlessly, thank you so much! I hadn't even thought about making it be in an ng-container, it's so simple that I feel dumb about it haha.

Comment: great! glad to help, Jordan! would you consider upvoting the answer as well? Trying real hard to get to the 1500 milestone :)

Comment: Yeah for sure dude! @Boris Lobanov , I just posted another question on SO if you want to give it a whirl? You seem to know more than I!